# Does convergence in distribution of marginals, and same conditional laws, imply convergence in distribution of the joint?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables in a Polish space, such that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$. Suppose also that we have random variables $Y_n,Y$ such that $\mathcal{L}(Y_n|X_n)=\mathcal{L}(Y|X)$ for all $n$.
Is this enough to conclude that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$?

Something I've been thinking about is showing whether the function $g(x)=\mathbb{E}[f(Y,X)|X=x]$ is continuous in $x$ when $f$ is continuous (or bounded and continuous), so that using averaging property and DCT I can show that $\lim_n\mathbb{E}[f(X_n,Y_n)])=\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)])$.  But I haven't been able to get around this.

*Does anyone know if this works? If it doesn't work in general, do you have a counter example? And in the latter case, does anyone know of conditions that would ensure the desired convergence?*

A partial answer I found is that If we can write $Y_n=F(X_n,U_n)$ (and thus $Y=F(X,U)$) for $X_n \perp U_n$, $X \perp U$, and  for a $F$ such that $x\rightarrow F(x,u)$ is continuous for all $u$, then I have the result I want as follows.

For $f$ bounded and continuous, we can rewrite $f(X_n,Y_n)=\tilde{f}(X_n,U_n)$, with $\tilde{f}$ is bounded, and continuous in the first argument. Then,
$$ \mathbb{E}[\tilde{f}(X_n,U_n)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\tilde{f}(X_n,U_n)| X_n]].$$

Now, $x\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[\tilde{f}(X_n,U_n) | X_n=x]$ is continuous by Dominated Convergence Theorem. Suppose $x_i\rightarrow x$, then:
$$ \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E} [\tilde{f}(X_n,U_n) | X_n=x_i]= \lim_{i\rightarrow i} \int \tilde{f}(x_i,u) \mu(du)\overset{DCT}{=} \int \lim_{i\rightarrow i}\tilde{f}(x_i,u) \mu(du)= \int \tilde{f}(x,u) \mu(du),$$
where $\mu=\mathcal{L}(U_n)=\mathcal{L}(U_n|X_n)$ (independence).

Then, since $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, it follows from the fact that $x\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[\tilde{f}(X_n,U_n) | X_n=x]$ is bounded and continuous that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{L}(Y_n\mid X_n)=\mathcal{L}(Y\mid X)$? Note that, in general it doesn't make sense to directly compare the regular conditional distributions $$(x,B)\mapsto\mathbb{P}(Y_n\in B\mid X_n=x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad(x,B)\mapsto\mathbb{P}(Y\in B\mid X=x).$$ My impression is that any reasonable setting that makes sense of the notion $\mathcal{L}(Y_n\mid X_n)=\mathcal{L}(Y\mid X)$ will naturally lead to the desired conclusion.